# Value of this missing when member function used as callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, ecmascript-6

I apologize for the newbness of this question.  I'm an experienced programmer but I'm new to javascript.  As such I might be using incorrect terminology.

I am trying to write my own middleware handler (as an exercise to better understand the asynchronous approach).  I am using a member function called `somethingsDone` defined on an object named `app` as a callback that I pass to outside callers.  When `somethingsDone` is called by clients, the value of `this` inside of it is undefined.  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

"use strict"

var YAML = require('js-yaml')
var fs = require('fs')

var app = {
  cb_index: 0,
  callbacks: [],
  finished_callback: null,

  use (fn) {
    this.callbacks.push(fn)
  },

  somethingsDone(req) {
    debugger
    // the callback at index this.cb_index is done
    if (this.cb_index == this.callback.count -1) {
      this.finished_callback(req)
    }
    this.cb_index += 1
    this.callbacks[this.cb_index]()
  },

  run (req, done) {
    this.finished_callback = done
    this.callbacks[0](req, this.somethingsDone)
  }
}

app.use((req, next) => {
  fs.readFile(req.filepath, (err, data) => {
    console.log(`Loaded file data from ${req.filepath}: ${data}`)
    req.contents = data
    next()
  })
})

app.use((req, next) => {
  setTimeout(2, () => {
    console.log('Dumping YAML')
    req.yaml = YAML.safeDump(input)
    next()
  })
})

app.use((req, next) => {
  console.log(`YAML data is:\n${req.yaml}`)
})

app.run({ filepath: "/home/ben/docker-compose.json"}, (req) => {
  console.log(`Hey we're finished!  Request data is:\n${req}`)
})
```

It fails with this error:

```
/home/ben/js-learning/middleware.js:20
if (this.cb_index == this.callback.count -1) {
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cb_index' of undefined
    at somethingsDone (/home/ben/js-learning/middleware.js:20:13)
    at /home/ben/js-learning/middleware.js:37:5
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

I have tried googling and reading about how `this` is set in javascript, but I'm not even sure how to search for this (I don't even know what this is called in javascript).

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get `this` to be properly defined when the callback is called?

Comment: `this` refers to the current context. So, when you pass the function as a callback, `this` is referencing the context where it is being called. You might want to look at [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks).

Comment: You assign `this` to a new variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys

Comment: Using `.bind` would probably the simplest solution here: `this.somethingsDone.bind(this)`.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I read the answer you linked to and `this.somethingsDone.bind(this)` definitely seems like the easiest solution.