# Polymer web app element null pointer exception

Tags: polymer, progressive-web-apps

I am user iron-list with iron-ajax but after ajax response when pushing element to iron-list giving null exception = "Cannot read property '_list' of undefined"

```
<script>

    Polymer({
        is: 'my-home',

        ready: function () {
            this.$._ajax.generateRequest();
        },

        onResponse: function (e) {

            var people = e.detail.response.data;
            people.forEach(function (person) {
                this.$._list.push('items', person);
            });
            // Clear the lower threshold so we can load more data when the user scrolls down again.
            this._scrollTheshold.clearTriggers();
        }

    });

</script>
```

here is my html code of iron-list

```
 <iron-list id="_list" items="[[data.data]]" as="item">
        <template>

            <div style="margin-top: 0px">

                <!--Card with header image http://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000-->
                <paper-card>

                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h1 class="feed_title">[[item.heading]]</h1>

                        <p class="feed_description">[[item.subheading]]</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-actions">
                        <paper-button class="button-blue">
                            Share
                        </paper-button>
                        <paper-button class="button-blue">
                            Explore
                        </paper-button>
                    </div>
                </paper-card>
            </div>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
```

Comment: I think `this` is not what you think :). Try suggestions from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this

Answer (score 1):

In your `forEach()` function expression, `this` refers to the `Window` object, and not the Polymer object. (If using [`"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) here, `this` would be `undefined`, but it seems that's not the case for you.)

A few options to fix this:

- Option 1: Use [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which does not bind its own `this` (assuming ES6 is available for you):

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    people.forEach(person => {
      this.$._list.push('items', person);
    });
    ...
  }
  ```
- Option 2: Use [ES6 `for-of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), removing need for callback (assuming ES6 is available for you):

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    for (const person of people) {
      this.$._list.push('items', person);
    });
    ...
  }
  ```
- Option 3: Use [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to push all array items at once (assuming ES6 is available for you):

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    this.$._list.push('items', ...people);
    ...
  }
  ```
- Option 4: Pass in a reference to the Polymer object:

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var self = this;
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    people.forEach(function (person) {
      self.$._list.push('items', person);
    });
    ...
  }
  ```
- Option 5: Pass in a reference to the list object:

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var list = this.$._list;
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    people.forEach(function (person) {
      list.push('items', person);
    });
    ...
  }
  ```
- Option 6: Explicitly bind `this` in your function expression:

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    people.forEach(function (person) {
      this.$._list.push('items', person);
    }.bind(this));
    ...
  }
  ```
- Option 7: Pass `this` as second parameter of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

  ```
  onResponse: function (e) {
    var people = e.detail.response.data;
    people.forEach(function (person) {
      this.$._list.push('items', person);
    }, this);
    ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Grate! Nice explanation for novice learner like me. Thank you very much

Comment: @user2837615 No problem

Comment: I think using `this` as second paremeter of `forEach` should be include
`people.forEach(function (person) {
  this.$._list.push('items', person);
}, this);`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @tony19's answer you can also achieve this with `bind`

```
people.forEach(function (person) {
  this.$._list.push('items', person);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Indeed. Option added.