# Why is passing $(this) as a parameter not working

Tags: jquery, html

How come the following line:

```
pop = setInterval(function () { doSlide($(this)) }, settings.timeoutSet);
```

not sending the proper reference as the parameter.

I would like to set up the same functionality as the commented out section in the `AutoSlide(theObj2)` function but using the class that was sent as the selector of the function but it's not working. I keep getting `[object][Object]` as the console log.

How can I resolve the issue so the auto sliding function works correctly.

Comment: There are already some questions quite like your, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts run in the context of `window`, unless told otherwise, so inside your callback `this` no longer points to the element, but `window` instead.

Instead, you can bind the callback to the element, i.e. set its context.

```
setInterval(function () { AutoSlide($(this)) }.bind(this), settings.timeoutSet);
```