# AngularJS scope variable can't be set inside of a timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a jsfiddle for this issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/uvtw5kp1/4/

```
$scope.Dropdown = {
  open: false,
  searchValue: "",

  timer: null,

  hideIt: function() {

    this.timer = $timeout(function() {
      alert("timeout happened the value will not change");
      this.open = false;
    }, 50);
  },
  hideItNotimer: function() {

    this.open = false;

  },
  showIt: function() {
    $timeout.cancel(this.timer);
    this.open = true;
  }
};
```

When I call Dropdown.hideItNotimer() on ng-mouseout it has no problem, but when I call Dropdown.hideIt() the variable is not set. I have added an alert to ensure the timer is working, and I've tried doing a scope.apply after. What does work is having a scope level function called within the timer:

like this:

```
 $scope.setDropdownHidden = function(){
   $scope.Dropdown.open = false;
 }
```

and call that from within the timeout it works, but I want to avoid this if I can.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout has its own scope since it is a closure, so the $scope.open = false is not updating your controller $scope.open variable, you should avoid using timeout for to update scope variables. You should bind the global scope with using bind as -

```
hideIt: function() {
  this.timer = $timeout(function() {
        this.open = false;
      }.bind(this), 50);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your timeout function, `this` does not refer to the Dropdown object, it instead probably refers to the `window` object.  In javascript `this` always refers to whichever object the function was invoked with, not the object in which it was defined.  When $timeout invokes your callback function it will do so with something other than your Dropdown object since it doesn't know about that object.

Related: [Javascript closures and `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this)

You need to either capture the value of `this` in the parent function as a closure variable or bind your callback function to the Dropdown object using [angular.bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind)