# exploring keyword "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I have following code block in javascript:

```js
const obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {
    const name = "sri2"

    function a() {
      console.log(this.name)
    }
    a();

  }
}

obj.func1();
```

why am I not getting any console.log state about the this keyword? I am really confused, its neither obj nor undefined nor window object

Comment: Do something like ```a.bind(this)();```

Comment: _"Ignore HTML part"_ ... if the HTML is not relevant then please do not include it in your example! I will edit the question for you, this time. Please see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I know bind exist but why am I not getting any output not even errors!

Comment: Ok sorry for adding html part

Comment: Ok I edited it into a runnable snippet. It does seem to produce output, albeit not the value you expected, I would assume. You maybe need to read up on the scope of `this` in functions, especially nested functions (or "closures" as they're sometimes known). You could potentially start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this

Comment: If you use arrow functions, you'll get a different result. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9ju3kbht/ . It wasn't clear which of the two "name" values you were actually expecting it to output? The demo shows how to get each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You log `window.name` in your function. It is '', if you don't set it.

Comment: so there is a name property in window object?

Answer (score 2):

When you have an object with a method that returns a function the `this` escapes the object scope and refers to the window, unless you bind it or use arrow functions.

So what your `this.name` is returning in a normal environment is just an empty string. That's why you don't see anything—like @dellink said. `window.name` is `""` if you don't set it. So what you actually see is just a string with nothing inside.

The reason why it's logging some weird property in your example is because of the Stack Overflow sandbox. Here, the `this` keyword does not refer to the general `window` object, but to a different object that *does* in fact have a `name` property with some value.

Check it:

```js
console.log(this.name)
```

Comment: when I rename all "name" to "names" and run the code I am getting undefined which means window.names don't exist

Comment: @sriramhegde you are exactly right. `window.names` does not exist.

Comment: then why does window.name exists?

Comment: The name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for hyperlinks and forms. 

You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name and here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp

Comment: thanks a lot for this info.You cleared my confusion

Answer (score 1):

tricky thing is that when you define a function `a` - it's getting defined in a global scope.

```
var obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {
    const name = "sri2"
    console.log(this); // obj (!) *2
    function a() {
      console.log(this); // window (!) *3
    }
    a();

  }
}
obj.func1();
console.log (a()) // window (!) *1
```

Look at point number 1: `a` function exists. And it's context is `window`. And this is what is happening in a first-place - defining functions and variables.

When you call "obj.func1();" it really calls in a context of `obj` (*2)

When you invoke `a` function context switch again to a window. (*3)

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {  // <-- 1
    const name = "sri2"

    function a() { // <-- 2
      console.log(this.name)
    }
    a();

  }
}
```

Normally `this` points to the `window` object of the browser.
But inside an object, if we define a property with an anonymous function then the `this` *points to the object itself.* But another function inside the function? No, it points to the `window` object.

So, for your example. I've marked your code with two reference points by comments.

1. Mark 1 function, it's the function of the object's property. So `this` points to the `obj` object.
2. Mark 2 function, it's inside the mark 1 function so now, `this` inside the function `a()` points to the `window` object. (*If you don't believe me then check it by using `console.log(this)` inside the `function a()`*)

## How can I get the object's `this` inside the inner function?

There are several ways to achieve this. I am mentioning few of them.

#### Using `arrow function`.

An arrow function doesn't alter the reference of `this` pointer. It points to the blocks `this` in which block the function lays.

```
const obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {
    const name = "sri2"

    const a = () => { // Using arrow function
      console.log(this.name)
    }

    a();
  }
}
```

#### Keep the previous `this` into a variable.

You can put the `this` into a variable say, `that`, then access the value using `that.name`.

```
const obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {
    const name = "sri2"
    const that = this; // Put this into that

    function a() {
      console.log(that.name); // Access the name using that.name
    }

    a();
  }
}
```

#### Bind `this` when you call the function.

You can bind the `this` with the function to use inside it.

```
const obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {
    const name = "sri2"

    function a() {
      console.log(this.name)
    }

    const withThis = a.bind(this); // Make a function reference with `this` bindings
    withThis(); // Call the function
  }
}
```

#### Using `call()` or `apply()`

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided >individually.
>
> While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of
>   `apply()`, the fundamental difference is that `call()` accepts an argument
>   list, while `apply()` accepts a single array of arguments.

```
const obj = {
  name: "sri1",
  func1: function() {
    const name = "sri2"

    function a() {
      console.log(this.name)
    }

    a.call(this); // call() binds the `this`
    // Or
    a.apply(this); // apply() also binds the `this`
  }
}
```